# Cannot delete folder: access denied

Tags: windows, windows-server

After a failed git-svn migration I somehow ended up with a folder which apparently is missing *any* ACLs because I cannot delete it:

- From Windows Explorer
- As administrator from Powershell
- As SYSTEM (`psexec -s -i cmd`)

In addition I:

- Cannot take ownership (`takeown /F repository /R` - access denied)
- Cannot change permissions (`icalcs` - access denied)
- Cannot check which permissions are assigned (SysInternals `accesschk` gives access denied)
- Tried scanning with `chkdsk`, but `chkdsk` does not see any issues.

How can I delete this folder? This folder is on the system drive of a Hyper-V VM.

Comment: Have you tried booting to WinRE and attempting the delete?  While it doesn't help to diagnose what the actual issue is, booting to a Linux LiveUSB should also allow deletion.

Comment: There are many utilities that can, but is outside of the scope here at SU as software recommendations are off topic as an answer but can be answered in a comment>>>>>>https://www.geckoandfly.com/5864/force-delete-locked-or-undeletable-files-and-folder-in-windows-7/